View coordinates of PDF on MacOS - pinlabel needed
I just moved to MacOS from Windows and I am trying to find an app that shows me the coordinates of a given point in a PDF file, which I need to use the package pinlabel.
On Windows I have always used GSview, which gives the coordinates of the pointer as you move it along the pdf picture, but apparently this software is not available for Macs.

as a quick hack, you could use preview and https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/359781/57046

Unluckily I cannot see the pixels after creating the rectangle :(

Tools->Show Inspector->crop tab should show a window with the coordinates of the selection.

Do you only want freeware? A significant number of (relatively inexpensive) apps exist that can offer you far better UI quality as well as allowing you to add the annotations directly to the PDF instead of doing back-and-forth between two systems. Indeed, even the free Preview app on macOS will allow you to annotate nicely. As such, perhaps you should be asking for these tools on a mac OS forum rather than here (try talk dot mac power users for example).

You could open the pdf in inkscape. There you can see the current coordinates of the mouse cursor at the bottom right (you can make some adjustments to the coordinate system in the preferences, like the position of the origin etc.)


Another possibility is gv, which is the modern version of ghostview.  One way of installing it on macOS is from MacPorts.

An alternative I found, very similar to GSview, is MacGhostView. This requires X11/XQuartz to make it work.

There is a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668031/how-to-get-the-x-y-coordinates-of-a-point-in-a-pdf
The top answer is:

Mac: Skim - Select a Text Box. Look on the bottom right for X,Y, plus the box height & width.

You can click on the coordinates in the bottom to change units (from points to centimeters).
I'm adding a screenshot to show it in action:

There's another similar question here, with other answers like GIMP and Apache PDFBox PDFDebugger:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971243/free-tool-for-watching-coordinates-in-pdf
